# Generating PDF file from HTML using any library

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf

I am aware that we can convert  html to pdf , by loading the html file in the web view and

taking the screen shot of it and then generating the pdf from it . I want to know, is there

any third party built in library to achieve my task ?

Comment: Use NDHTMLtoPdf. View this question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244819/ios-converting-html-page-to-pdf-using-ndhtmltopdf-libraries

Answer (score 0):

The problem with generating PDF from UIWebView is that you have very little control about the details that will show up in your PDF. For example, page breaking is a pain, and sometimes there are UI elements visible, such as the shading at the end of the scroll view.

I have tried this and could not get acceptable results. I recommend you use the Core Graphics methods to construct your own PDF.

Comment: Yea I have read it some where . But as of now since Iam running out of time I need a quick approach

Comment: As I said , I successfully generated PDF from html by loading html into web view and taking the snapshot of it . I feel this is time consuming as it takes some time to generate snapshots

Comment: Not really. The actual snapshot is just done with a single core graphics call `renderInContext` which is very fast.

Comment: Can u suggest me some links , to use core graphics to achieve my task .

Comment: Usually [these tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6581/how-to-create-a-pdf-with-quartz-2d-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1) by Ray Wenderlich are excellent. Please consider ticking the check mark above.

Comment: The tutorial u gave is converting the text to pdf . What I want is , convert html to pdf

Comment: That is the same thing. With HTML you convert text into text with styling (such as fonts, layout, etc.). By writing your own PDF with the core graphics API you are replicating these style elements. Sorry, there is no other way. Nevertheless, is quite simple with just a few new methods to learn.